# Is it possible to simplify this LIKE statement and get rid of duplication?

Tags: sql-server

There are few rows in a table:

1. just text, should not be selected
2. ...parameter1:...
3. ...parameter2:...
4. ...parameter:...
5. ...parameter7:... should not be selected

I use this query to select parameters but it looks like some kind of duplication. Can you tell me, please, is it possible to simplify "where" clause and combine this likes into single one?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE text LIKE '%parameter[1-2]:%' OR text LIKE '%parameter:%'
```

Comment: `parameter[12:]`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert That will match `parameter17:` and `parameter2345678:` which may or may not be desired.

Comment: True. If not, my answer is "no, that can't be simplified, as you can't combine both positive and negative matches in a single wildcard block".